# Swift how to hide info window programmatically

Tags: swift, google-maps

I'm using google map for swift. I would to know if theres a method that I can use to hide the info Window whenever I use the delegate `will move`

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, willMove gesture: Bool) {
    if gesture {
                  // Hide info window here
    }
}
```

map
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The active info window is stored in selectedMarker of GMSMapView.
Set it to nil and the info window will disappear.

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, willMove gesture: Bool) 
{
  if mapView.selectedMarker != nil
  {
    mapView.selectedMarker = nil
  }
}
```